# Replace constexpr (used to calculate constant at compile time) with template?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, constexpr, visual-studio-2012

I use the `constexpr` keyword to calculate the maximum integer value able to be stored in a float or double at compile time (n is the number of bits in the mantissa, val is initially 1.0):

```
constexpr double calc_max_float(int n, double val)
{
    return (n == 0) ? (val) : calc_max_float(n - 1, 2.0*val);
}
```

This value is generated for use by the following template(s):

```
template <bool, class L, class R>
struct IF  // primary template
{
    typedef R type;
};

template <class L, class R>
struct IF<true, L, R> // partial specialization
{
    typedef L type;
};

template<class float_type>
inline float_type extract_float()
{
    return (extract_integer<typename IF<sizeof(float_type) == 4,
                                        uint32_t,
                                        uint64_t
                                       >::type
                           >() >> (8*sizeof(float_type) - std::numeric_limits<float_type>::digits))*(1./calc_max_float(std::numeric_limits<float_type>::digits, 1.0));
}
```

This template generates two functions, equivalent to:

```
inline float extract_single()
{
    return (extract_integer<uint32_t>() >> 9) * (1./(8388608.0));
}
inline double extract_double()
{
    return (extract_integer<uint64_t>() >> 12) * (1./(67108864.0*67108864.0));
}
```

All is well in GCC however I'd lke to be able to compile with VC11/12 also. Any thoughts on how to replace `constexpr calc_max_float(int n, double val)`?

EDIT:

To be clear, I'm looking for a way to use templates to calculate a constant pow(2,x) at compile time. Even a point in the right direction would be great.

As for examples of usage, I have a function extract_integer(type min, type range) which works with any signed or unsigned type. I am trying to create a function extract_float() which returns a value [0,1) of type float or double.

I think I'm looking for something like:

```
template <const unsigned  N, const uint64_t val>
inline uint64_t calc_max_float()
{
    return calc_max_float<N - 1,2*val>();
}

template <const uint64_t val>
inline double calc_max_float<0, val>()
{
    return (double) val;
}
```

However partial specialization for functions is not allowed? And while we are at it, why wouldn't something like

```
template <const unsigned  N, const uint64_t val>
inline uint64_t calc_max_float()
{
    return (N != 0) ? calc_max_float<N - 1,2*val>() : val;
}
```

work?

Comment: You have no examples of how it's used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned  N>
inline double calc_max_float(double val)
{
    return calc_max_float<N - 1>(2.0 * val);
}

template <>
inline double calc_max_float<0>(double val)
{
    return val;
}

int main() {
    // 2 ^ 3
    std::cout << calc_max_float<3>(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is good, but it calculates the constant at run-time. I'm looking for a way to calculate it during compile-time. Thanks!

Comment: @bhimberg trust the compiler!

Comment: Indeed. Timed run for 5E10 calls for the template version (without `constexpr`) and extract_single() yield ~34 seconds. I had checked the call stack with a debugging version and found it called the template/`constexpr` versions recursively at run-time, but I guess -O3 trumps that? Thanks again!